# Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL not working for calendar events in new calendar version by Google

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

Seems like there is a regression with Google calendar app (since version 5.0): trying to generate new intents for calendar events with Google demo code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html doesn't really add the participants added through the EXTRA_EMAIL.

I even tried running their demo code (which worked in former versions):

```
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
        .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
        .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

Anyone has any idea? Is it really a bug in the new app?

Comment: have you any work around? I see that it's a bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81710&q=EXTRA_EMAIL&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars